# fitting long text in GridView Column

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am having issues displaying long text in a ASP.NET gridview column. I don't want the text to wrap on to the second line as it is one the business requirements not to wrap.

Ideally I want some sort of server or client based code which can help me truncate the text to the size of the column and then maybe display a more button or '...' for more text?

and when the more button or ... are clicked; a pop up appears either with rest of the text or full text.

note: the text or string size varies and it can be any of length from 25 to 75 characters.

any ideas on how should i go about achieving the above? thanks

Comment: What you can do is add a maxWidth to the colums, and add a tooltip service that displays the all text, when you go over the cell.

Comment: tooltip service? can you please explain that a bit more. thanks

Comment: The `ToolTip` attribute of an ASP element translates into the `title` attribute of the HTML node. It's a text hint that appears when you hover over the node with the mouse.

Answer (score 5):

Use this CSS class for the gridview column

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It puts ... in the end of the column in a specific width.

### **Update**

***Markup***

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="employees-grid">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="employees-grid-id" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First Name">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="employees-grid-first-name" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last Name">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="employees-grid-last-name" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="employees-grid-email" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="note" HeaderText="Note">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="employees-grid-note" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

***CSS***

```
.employees-grid {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.employees-grid-id {
    width: 5%;   
}
.employees-grid-first-name {
    width: 10%; 
}
.employees-grid-last-name {
    width: 10%;   
}
.employees-grid-email {
    width: 15%; 
}
.employees-grid-note {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Mine is getting data from a SP list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979966/how-to-set-ellipses-on-a-column-data-if-it-exceeds-more-than-a-set-record. How can i implement your idea?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Just set the "CssClasss" of the column.                        
<asp:BoundField DataField="dataField" HeaderText="Header Text">
<ItemStyle CssClass="ellipsis"/></asp:BoundField>

Comment: @AbbasAmiri: This is straightforward solution !!
May I suggest to add your comment about adding css class to column to the main answer.
Also, can we quote the width in percentage ? Tried lots of suggestion but couldn't get it working correctly.

Comment: @MilindThakkar, Thank you for your comment. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about formatting, I would build my query (the one you're binding your GridView to) so that the data is returned in two forms.

```
Select Left(dataColumn, 20) as TruncatedData, dataColumn as FullData From table
```

You can then bind your GridView to the TruncatedData column, with a tooltip bound to the FullData column, so that when they hover, they get the full column data.  I'd convert a `BoundField` into a `TemplateField` and fill it thus:

```
          <asp:templatefield>
              <itemtemplate>
                  <asp:label id="lblData"
                      Text= '<%# Eval("TruncatedData") %>'
                      runat="server"
                      ToolTip='<%# Eval("FullData") %>' /> 
              </itemtemplate>
          </asp:templatefield>
```

Comment: Mine is getting data from a SP list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979966/how-to-set-ellipses-on-a-column-data-if-it-exceeds-more-than-a-set-record. How can i implement your idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code you have tried, such that people can propose changes/improvements, etc. In any case, I had to write a code doing something on the lines of what you are looking for anyway, so here you have it.

```
private string[] truncateText(string iniText, int colNumber, int noAddRows)
{
    string[] outStrings = new string[noAddRows + 3];
    if (noAddRows == 0)
    {
        outStrings = new string[22];
    }
    outStrings[1] = iniText;
    int addBit = 10;
    int maxLength = (int)GridView1.Columns[colNumber].ItemStyle.Width.Value + addBit;
    int linesCount = 1;

    if (iniText.Length > maxLength)
    {
        outStrings[1] = iniText.Substring(0, maxLength); //New truncated string
        outStrings[2] = iniText.Substring(maxLength, iniText.Length - maxLength); //Remaining bit
        linesCount = 2;
        if (noAddRows > -1 && outStrings[2].Length > maxLength)
        {
            //Further lines of the truncated bit
            string remBit = outStrings[2].Substring(maxLength, outStrings[2].Length - maxLength);
            outStrings[2] = outStrings[2].Substring(0, maxLength);
            while (remBit.Length > 0)
            {
                linesCount = linesCount + 1;
                if ((noAddRows > 0 && linesCount > noAddRows + 2) || linesCount > 20)
                {
                    linesCount = linesCount - 1;
                    if (remBit.Length > 0)
                    {
                        outStrings[linesCount] = outStrings[linesCount] + remBit;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (remBit.Length <= maxLength)
                {
                    outStrings[linesCount] = remBit;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    outStrings[linesCount] = remBit.Substring(0, maxLength);
                    remBit = remBit.Substring(maxLength, remBit.Length - maxLength);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    outStrings[0] = Convert.ToString(linesCount); //Total number of lines

    return outStrings;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
string[] truncatedLines = truncateText("text to truncate", colNo, noAdd);
```

The output `string[]` holds all the lines truncated such that they fit within the width of the given column + a small bit (`addBit` which I set to 10). With the `noAddRows` parameter you control the number of lines you want as output: if it is set to zero, it returns as many lines as required on account of the given column width. The 0 position of the array is reserved for the total number of lines returned.

I guess that you will not find any problem to use this code to have full control on the functionality you want to implement.