# Responsive columns content does not overflow

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to create a table where column 1, 3 and 4 are as big as the content needs to be displayed in a single row. Column 2 gets bigger and smaller when browser window rezises. Content in column 2 should also stay single row and overflow.
But I fail to get content overflowing correctly. It appears in the next columns.

A screenshot when I size my browser very small:
[Very small table where all texts in column 2 overflows into next column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlWxd.png)

A screenshot how it should overflow:
[Edited picture how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0XZn.png)

I use Visual Studio 2013, ASP.net Web Forms and Bootstrap v3.3.6. I have no custom CSS file which overwrites bootstrap.css.

This is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_OpenTickets" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#00136F" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_OpenTickets">
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10px"/>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <div style="overflow-x:auto hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;width:10px">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label_Title" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Assignment" HeaderText="Assignment" SortExpression="Assignment" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10px"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Affected Item" HeaderText="Affected Item" SortExpression="Affected Item" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10px"/>
      </Columns>
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
          <div>Yay, no unassigned tickets.</div>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_OpenTickets" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ServiceManager_prodConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Select Dummy">   <%--Select Statement from CodeBehind--%>        
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks for your help!

Lukas

Comment: Here are two topics similar to your question. [Fitting long text in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680370/fitting-long-text-in-gridview-column) and [Limit text size in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650791/limit-text-size-in-gridview-column). Hope these help.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that posts in my research. They solved it with fixed width columns, but I want to have my column flexible. If I set a fixed width and take the "auto" away from "overflow-x" i achieve the same result as them.